# Generating rsa key pair - bad address

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I am trying to deploy php app on heroku by following this tutorial 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction

Currently on this step
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#deploy-the-app

when I run the command "git push heroku master" it gives the following error
"**C:\Windows\System32\php-getting-started>git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**"

Then I used this command for generating keypair : ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@gmail.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku

Error is :
**C:\Windows\System32\php-getting-started>ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@gmail.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku" failed: Bad address**

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
id_rsa_heroku
```

you have not used the default ssh key names so you must have a configuration file to map the key to your account.

change it to the default name of use this configuration template:

> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName <host1> 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```

The default names for the ssh-keys are `~/.ssh/id_rsa` without the **_heroku** part which you added.

More informations can be found [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204644730/using-an-ssh-config-file)

Comment: how can i know my default ssh key name ?

Comment: its simply: `id_rsa`

Comment: I have tried this 
**C:\Windows\System32\php-getting-started>ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@gmail.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa**

But again the same error
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "~/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: Bad address

Comment: delete the old keys and than create the new ones

Comment: I have no ssh keys , I used this command to check **heroku keys**
The output is
 **!    You have no SSH keys.**